# JQuery If Statement using each value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, scroll

I am writing a function that will be executed on multiple views of an application, and each view can have up to 50 instances of the same element: '.console'. I need to be able to perform an action every time the viewport scrolls to each instance. I have the following code setting up the variables:

```
  //Create empty array with variable values, up to 50 
  var console = [];

  //Find each instance of ".console" and populate the array with its pixel position.
  $('.console').each(function() {
    console.push($(this)[0].offsetTop);
  });

  //Determine the current pixel position of the scroll
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
```

Those variables all work fine and dandy, but after hours of pouring over jquery docs I can't figure the if statement out. Here is what I have that works well for the first item in the array:

```
  if (scroll == console[0]){
    $('.container').show();
  } else {
    $('.container').hide();
  }
```

However, I want it to be anytime the scroll position matches each of the values in that array, hopefully something like this:

```
if (scroll == console[0-50])
```

Here is the full chunk as is:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){

  //Create empty array with variable values, up to 50 
  var console = [];

  //Find each instance of ".console" and populate the array with its pixel position.
  $('.console').each(function() {
    console.push($(this)[0].offsetTop);
  });

  //Determine the current pixel position of the scroll
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

  //Anytime the scroll matches any of the instances of console, show a div
  if (scroll == console[0]){
    $('.container').show();
  } else {
    $('.container').hide();
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am pretty new to Javascript/JQuery so if I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way altogether, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What is the relationship between `.console` elements and `.container` elements?

Comment: You only want to execute this when the scroll **exactly** matches the position of the `.console`?  Seems like the odds of that are pretty small.

Comment: '.container' has some buttons that control other parts of the app (nothing within '.console'), but are only applicable when the '.console' is in view.

Comment: "is in view" and matching a specific number is two different things ?

Comment: @JamesMontagne It will ultimately be a range, like +/- 100px, but for the sake of simplicity in the question I omitted that qualification.

Comment: @adeneo yes, because there could potentially be two instances of '.console' in view at the same time. The whole thing is a little more complex than I'm letting on in the question, I stripped out the unnecessary stuff to get at the meat of the question–how to make that if statement work the way I want :(

Comment: the line `$(this)[0].offsetTop` is redundant, you can do `this.offsetTop`. Could you add the .container html & related style info to your question?

Comment: var console ? you like to play with fire hehe... maybe rename to var window.

Comment: @Austin, I added a link to the full markup in context to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the problem was solved via another answer, figuring out how to perform a loop for each value in the array wasn't really solved ... UNTIL NOW!

This is probably a really gross and bloated way to do it, but if you essentially count how many items are in the array, you can then run a loop that many times, putting in the index for each value in the array. Code below:

```
//Create empty array with variable values
var console = [];

//Find each instance of ".console" and populate the array with its pixel position.
$('.console').each(function() {
    console.push($(this)[0].offsetTop);
});

//Count the number of items in the array
var consoleIndex = console.length - 1;

    $(document).on('scroll', function(){

        //Determine the current pixel position of the scroll
        var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

        //Anytime the scroll matches any of the instances of console, show a div
        for (var i = 0; i <= consoleIndex; i++) {
            if (scroll = console[i]) {
                $('.container').toggle();
            }
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it works for the first one, I'm guessing this may work.

```
// cache the container     
var container = $('.container');

$(document).on('scroll', function(){

  //Determine the current pixel position of the scroll
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

  //Create empty array with variable values, up to 50 
  var console = [];

  //Find each instance of ".console" and populate the array with its pixel position.
  $('.console').each(function(index) {
    console.push($(this)[0].offsetTop);
    if (scroll == console[index]){
      $(container).show();
    } else {
      $(container).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I really wanted this to work, but it only ends up working with the last value in the array, not each.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you could do this:

```
var cons = $.map($('.console'), function(el) {
    return $(el).offset().top;
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.container').toggle( $.inArray(scroll, cons) != -1 );
});
```

But creating something for a range, considering the height of each element, the height of the window etc. would be a lot more involved.

Comment: This worked, but I have no idea why. Can you explain this line: '$('.container').toggle( $.inArray(scroll, cons) != -1 );' ? Thanks!

Comment: @TimDikun - `toggle()` is `show()` and `hide()` in one, and it accepts `true` or `false` to show or hide, so checking if the value is in the array returns true or false, and sticking that inside `toggle()`, will in turn shows or hide the container.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't necessarily help me figure out a loop for each value in the array like I wanted, but it achieved the desired effect and set me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to take a look at [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). It's a jQuery plugin that is well suited for what you're trying to accomplish.

I whipped up a quick jsFiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/dmillz/4xqMb/

```
$(".console").waypoint(function(direction) {
    // Hide or show your ".container" object
});
```

More Waypoint examples: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#get-started

Comment: Thanks! This is more of a mental exercise for me, and I'd really like to avoid using a plugin if I can. If I can't get it I'll definitely check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your problem, which is as follows:

You have a bunch of elements with the `.console` class, and you want to appear as soon as they are in the viewport.  When these elements aren't in the viewport you want them to dissapear?

Since you're interested in when these objects with the `.console` class are in the viewport, I suggest using this jQuery plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/appear/

https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear

I suggest wrapping each of the `.console` objects in a container with another class, and then as these containers appear and disappear show and hide them.

At document ready just do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('<.container-class>').appear();

   $('<.container-class>').on('appear', function() { $(this).find('.console').show(); });

   $('<.container-class>').on('disappear', function() { $(this).find('.console').hide(); });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a cool plugin, but I need it to be a little more specific than just in the viewport.